# What is the best way to have a div go to the upper right?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with an image in it, and I want to have it positioned in the upper right and then have text wrap around it with a little padding:

I tried stuff like this, but it didn't seem to work.

```
.slideshow
{
    position:absolute;
    right:10;
    top:10;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "it didn't seem to work"?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - how would i add padding to this ??

Comment: you would add left and bottom padding to the image `<div>` itself, and let the floating mode wrap the text around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `px` to your positions?

```
.slideshow { position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; }
```

Comment: float: right seems to work but i can't seem to then add padding to that

Comment: If you want there to be space on the outside use `margin` instead of `padding`.  Padding is inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

This works well. I tested it.

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="float:right;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```